# How do i set a open_basedir with php using fastcgi/apache2 on linux?

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, fastcgi, php.ini, open-basedir

I tried to add this line to my virtual hosts in Apache, but failed:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/users/test"
```

My installation:

```
root# apt-get install apache2 apache2-suexec libapache2-mod-fcgid php5-cgi
```

**Any ideas?**

Something I noticed in php manual that worried me enough (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php): `open_basedir` is marked as `PHP_INI_ALL` meaning `"Entry can be set anywhere"` so, even at run-time a user can change it or am I having wrong?*

(*: confirmed, user can NOT change it at run-time)

Answer (score 0):

Setting php ini options in the apache config only affects php when running as an apache module. For CGI / FastCGI, the setting need to be added to the php.ini (or via ini_set - but this doesn't make much sense for open_basedir unless it's via an auto-prepend).

Comment: So, we can simply set it at php.ini as long as user is not allowed to edit it! 'auto-prepend' feature gives me some ideas for increased security(?!). Thanks.